# how to set default g++?

Tags: c++, g++, version, default

My host has installed c++11 and g++ 4.7.2 (I'm told), but we can't figure out how to set 4.7.2 to default as `g++ --version` still says I'm 4.1.2.

Stack has shown me that I can't [sort multidimensional vector of ints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669533/sort-multidimensional-vector-of-ints?lq=1) without [cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11" with g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674597/cc1plus-error-unrecognized-command-line-option-std-c11-with-g), but all of the answers I come across for setting the default don't seem to work.

**CentOS 5.9**

I'm using CentOS 5.9, and I have no idea if that's the issue, but I tried `g++-4.7` and `g++-4.7.2` from [How to change version of g++ compiler from 4.1.2 to 4.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916502/how-to-change-version-of-g-compiler-from-4-1-2-to-4-5), but SSH says `sudo: apt-get: command not found` and `-bash: g++-4.7: command not found`
 for both (`.2` for .2).  If I put a space before `-4.7`, it says `g++: unrecognized option '-4.7'`.

I tried the suggested solution from the A of my last c++ q [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14674646/1382306), and the command executes without error, but nothing is returned, and `g++ --version` still gives:

```
g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

**GCC?**

I've seen this associated with g++ on many links, but I don't even know what it is, and I'm afraid to try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/choose-gcc-and-g-version) for risk of nuking my system.

My host says this is the limit of their support, so I'm totally on my own.  Also, please understand that I just started C++ a week or two ago and have no knowledge of linux.

Please help!  Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Try the good old `find / -name g++\*`.

Comment: @HristoIliev thank-you!  I did that, and it showed 2 files: `/usr/share/man/man1/g++.1.gz` and `/usr/bin/g++`

Comment: Then GCC 4.7.2 is nowhere to be found on your system. Perhaps you have been told wrong.

Comment: @HristoIliev yup, just found out.  admin just used default `yum` which only installs 4.1.2 even with latest centos rpms.  now, i'm stuck on this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63587/how-to-install-g4-7-2-c11-on-centos  thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have multiple applications providing similar functionality, official mechanism to choose preferred application is `update-alternatives`.

Try using this:

```
 sudo update-alternatives --config g++
```

If you have more than one version of gcc installed, it will give you option to make one of them default.

Sometimes, alternatives are not installed - probably omission by package maintainer. You can fix it by installing it manually, something like this:

```
 sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.4 20
```

---

Alternatively, you can create symbolic links directly to desired `g++`/`gcc` from your `~/bin`, and add `$HOME/bin` to the beginning of your `PATH`. See more details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365348/is-it-possible-to-build-aosp-project-gingerbread-in-kubuntu12-04-xubuntu/13415103#13415103).

Comment: thank-you!  someone else suggested that, and I tried, but it just looks like it executes without error, prints nothing, and returns to the command line

Comment: sometimes alternative is not installed. I have updated my answer with info how to fix it. There is also 3rd way with using local symlinks (to leave system gcc alone).

Comment: do you think it's because I'm using CentOS 5.9?  neither commands worked.  do you know how to check if g++ 4.7.2 is truly installed (not just in the path or whatever with `g++ --version`)?

Comment: `rpm -qa | grep g++`. as last resort, using [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365348/is-it-possible-to-build-aosp-project-gingerbread-in-kubuntu12-04-xubuntu/13415103#13415103) will definitely work

Comment: I just found out that CentOS uses `yum` not `sudo`.  Do you happen to know what the alternative commands would be?  Thanks a lot for all of your help on this!

Comment: it is possible that `sudo` is not configured. in that case `su` to root, and then execute provided commands without `sudo` prefix.

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy: `yum` and `sudo` do different things. You can't replace one with the other. CentOS has both.